# Simple math question about frame buffers

Tags: math

How do you get row back out of n?

```
local n = row * cols + col
local c = n % cols
local r = ?
```

Comment: Ah ok :) I tried n / cols heh

Comment: using integer-division (i.e. truncating the result to an integer) the `n/cols` should work.

Answer (score 3):

Using some simple arithmetic...

You have

```
n = rows * cols + col
```

subtract `col` from both sides

```
n - col = rows * cols
```

divide by `cols` on both sides

```
(n - col) / cols = rows
```

---

Assuming `col < cols` holds, you could do it with integer division as `rows = n / cols`.

Comment: Algebra betrays me ;) I've got dyscalculia. Yet I'm a programmer. Go figure. I just like making computers do things. Some interesting stuff is out of my reach, but I'm happy with what I do. Besides that's what Stackoverflow is all about right? :) I admit I ask more questions than I answer.

Answer (score 0):

local r = int( n / cols )

Comment: there's always a dilemma in cases like this. Downvote someone with 1 rep? It just doesn't make sense. SO should allow negative rep.

Comment: I'm upvoting. @aaronasterling, You should be *very* careful when down-voting. There's nothing wrong with this answer. It's perhaps even preferable over mine. Since the current column (`col`) will always be less than the number of columns (`cols`), taking the integer part of `n / cols` is perfectly valid. You can't take back your down-vote unless he edits the answer, so let this situation be a lesson for down-voting.